# Display Django TextField in Template (Django 2+)

Tags: python, django, textfield

I am trying to display some content in my database to a template, my model is this below and am trying to access only about inside About_us so as it can be displayed in the template.

```py
class About_us(models.Model):
    welcome_to= models.TextField(max_length=None)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=None)
    vision_mission = models.TextField(max_length=None)
    organization_structure = models.TextField(max_length=None)
```

in my views file this is what i have

```py
def about(request):
    content = About_us._meta.get_field('about').db_column
    return render(request, 'aboutenos.html', {'content': content})
```

But the text in the database doesn't show it only shows "None"

```html
<p>
{{ content.content }}
</p>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display information about the database schema or a row in the database?

Comment: You have a table `About_us` with multiple rows (`About_us.objects.all()` can return multiple objects). Which row are you trying to display the `about` for?

Comment: #dirkgroten i am trying to create one model which can edit different values in different pages, say homepage, contact page, news page etc

Comment: #Sayse lets say my database has id, one, two, three, so i want only to display the value of three, in the template

Answer (score 0):

I think u should replace your query with this:

```
content = About_us.objects.values('about')
```

The `values()` function only fetch needed columns.

Comment: okay when i call content alone it shows "<QuerySet [{'about': 'Welcome again'}]>" but i just wanted it to show Welcome again in the template

Comment: A queryset is just a list with dictionary data. you can get that value with:  
`content[0].['about']`  
Or if u got more results you can iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to do this:

```
def about(request):
    content = About_us.objects.values('about').get()
    return render(request, 'aboutenos.html', {'content': content})
```

Then at the template I did this:

```
<p>
    {{ content.about }}
</p>
```

And it worked for me.